# Value of an html element edited

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, contenteditable, onblur

Why this code does not work in Firefox?
The goal is to get the edited value when the element loses focus

```js
out = document.getElementById('out');
edit = function(e) {
  var element = e;
  element.contentEditable = true;
  element.onblur = function(blur) {
    console.log(element.innerText);
    out.innerText = element.innerText;
  };
};
```

```css
span {
  background-color: cyan;
}
#out {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<span ondblclick="edit(this)" data-foo="foo" data-bar="bar">
    double-click and edit-me</span>

<p></p>
<span id="out"></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support `.innerText`. You should use the W3 standard `.textContent` instead.

This will work in all modern browsers and can be patched into IE8 if needed.

Comment: (Firefox doesn't support .innerText.) I think This is a **Wrong** information, **Firefox support `.innerText`** ,See basic fiddle example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/e3wm2kv0/1/).

Comment: Ok i'm really sorry @squint it's my fault, thanks and good luck.